# Cancan Thinking Sphinx current_ability Questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx, cancan

trying to get cancan working with thinking sphinx but running into some issues.

Before using sphinx, I had this in my companies view:

```
@companies = Company.accessible_by(current_ability)
```

That prevented my users from seeing anyone else's companies...

After installing sphinx, I ended up with:

```
  @companies = Company.accessible_by(current_ability).search(params[:search], :include => :order, :match_mode => :extended ).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Which now displays all my companies and isn't refining per user based on ability.

It would see ts isn't set up for cancan?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's more that `accessible_by` is probably a scope - which is Database/SQL-driven. Sphinx has its own query interface, and so ActiveRecord scopes don't apply.

An inefficient workaround (gets all companies first):

```
company_ids = Company.accessible_by(current_ability).collect &:id
@companies  = Company.search params[:search],
  :include    => :order,
  :match_mode => :extended,
  :page       => params[:page],
  :with       => {:sphinx_internal_id => company_ids}
```

A couple of things to note: sphinx_internal_id is the indexed model's primary key - Sphinx has its own unique identifier named id, hence the distinction. Also: You don't want to call `paginate` on a search collection - Sphinx always paginates, so just pass the `:page` param through to the search call.

There'd be two better workarounds that I can think of - either have a Sphinx equivalent of `accessible_by`, with the relevant information added to your indices as attributes - or, simpler if not quite as ideal, just get the company ids returned in the first line of my above snippet *without* loading up every company as an ActiveRecord object. Both will probably mean bypassing and/or duplicating Cancan's helpers.

Although... maybe this would do the trick, taking the latter approach:

```
sql         = Company.accessible_by(current_ability).select(:id).to_sql
company_ids = Company.connection.select_values sql
@companies  = Company.search params[:search],
  :include    => :order,
  :match_mode => :extended,
  :page       => params[:page],
  :with       => {:sphinx_internal_id => company_ids}
```

Avoids loading unnecessary Company objects, uses the Cancan helper (provided it is/returns a scope), and works neatly with what Sphinx/Thinking Sphinx expects. I've not used Cancan though, so this is a bit of guesswork.

Comment: Wow, slightly more complex than I'd hoped... Let me digest your approach - really appreciate you taking the time to answer

Comment: It's also worth noting Ryan Bates (author of Cancan) has confirmed that accessible_by is a scope, so the final solution should do the trick. Any questions, let me know :)

Comment: Is there a way to pass sql directly to thinking_sphinx? This solution is awesome, but it seems like it would have trouble scaling, if the company_ids array got large.

Comment: Sphinx doesn't understand SQL when it's dealing with searches - it only talks to the database when indexing - so giving it a SQL query as part of a search won't work.