# Thinking sphinx with privacy settings using facets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, authorization, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying to use Thinking Sphinx with my Can Can solution for authorization.

I found this answer helpful [Cancan Thinking Sphinx current_ability Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610426/cancan-thinking-sphinx-current-ability-questions), but was wondering if there might be a way to accomplish this with facets.

So I have projects, where there is a column called `privacy` which is a bool. If a project is private then there is an index for `collaborator_ids`, which is a list of all of the users that can view the project.

I was wondering if there is a way to form a query using facets to return all projects that are either public OR private and the user's id is in the `collaborator_ids`.

---

Another approach I'm considering is formulating an extended query in my controller to check for these fields. http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how you would do it thinking sphinx, but in normal sphinx this should work..

```
$cl->setSelect("*,privacy+IF(IN($user_id,collaborator_ids),1,0) AS myint");
$cl->setFilter('myint',array(1,2));
```

Which effectily makes an 'OR' query.

As I say, cant help you write thatin in thinging-sphinx.